# Using Ramda to accumulate sum of values in objects

Tags: ramda.js

I have an object like this:

```
obj = {
'key1': {'prop1': 123,'prop2':345},
'key2': {'prop1': 673,'prop3':642}
}
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
result = {'prop1': 796, 'prop2':345, 'prop3':642}
```

That is, I want a single object that has all properties. I have a function like this:

```
Object.values(obj).reduce((acc,currentObj) => {
        const props = Object.keys(currentObj);
        props.forEach(prop => {
            if(prop in acc){
                acc[prop] += currentObj[prop]
            } else {
                acc[prop] = currentObj[prop]
            }
        })
        return acc
    }, {})
```

I believe this works fine, but is there any way to do the same with RamdaJS?

Comment: I'm not in front of a computer to test right now, but this sounds like a use for `mergeWith`.  Perhaps `compose(reduce(mergeWith(add), {}), values) `? This is entirely untested and I may be way off, but it looks close to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple reduce function would do that.

```js
const fn = R.pipe(
  R.values,
  R.reduce(R.mergeWith(R.add), {}),
);

//--

const data = {
  key1: { prop1: 123, prop2: 345 },
  key2: { prop1: 673, prop3: 642 },
};


console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```